# Calling Quartz Scheduler In Non Periodic Time Interval

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

In quartz scheduler I have a doubt

**For example**

If we schedule job for every 5 minutes or 10 minutes or 2 hours it is ok we call scheduler using regular time interval like below no problem,

```
    SimpleTrigger simpleTrigger = new SimpleTrigger("mytrigger",sched.DEFAULT_GROUP,new Date(),null,SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY,30L*5000L);
```

But,If I schedule job @ 2'0 clock and 3'0 clock today then,tommorow I change it to  5'0 clock and 7'0 clock and 11'0 clock, my doubt is if fixed interval we call it in above way but it not fixed or periodic interval how do we handle it. Any suggestions or Ideas or examples regarding my query....

Comment: maybe start daily job for each hour and job will check if his hour is ok to run task.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is define the intervals in a file or DB and read it from there.

Also define a [JobListener](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/JobListener.html).

Store the interval values in the [JobDataMap](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/JobDataMap.html) and every time the job starts, use the listeners method [jobToBeExecuted()](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/JobListener.html#jobToBeExecuted%28org.quartz.JobExecutionContext%29) and read the values from the file/DB and compare it with the values in the `JobDataMap`.

If they are the same, then no update was done and the job runs, if it was changed, reschedule the job using `Scheduler.rescheduleJob(TriggerKey triggerKey,Trigger newTrigger)`.

Note that there is a little problem with this method, the configuration will only change once the job runs, so even though you update the file/DB the next run would still be in the old time, and only the run after that would be in the new time.